# Syntax problem with textfield as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, syntax, textfield

I have this code

```
gameOver1.text = (count1.currentCount / 100).toString();
```

but i want to add some text before i display the current count. for instance in gameOver1.text i want to say

Score : (and then the count)

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just use : 
`gameOver1.text = "Score" + (count1.currentCount / 100).toString();`

Action script was derived from ECMA script. One of the reasons as to why it's similar to javascript with features like string manipulation. Apart from string concatenation, other examples include:

- myString.charAt(0);
- myString.substring(0,4);
- myString.substring(4);
- myString.slice(4,9);
- myString.search("Word");
- myString.toLowerCase();
- myString.toUpperCase();
- myString.length;
- myString.replace(myString.substring(0,3),
  "New");

Comment: you also don't need the `toString()` at the end, it'll make the conversion automatically. i.e. `gameOver1.text = "Score" + (count1.currentCount / 100);`

Comment: yea rite. I guess I didn't implement what I suggested in my own second line.

Answer (score 2):

```
var score:Number = count1.currentCount / 100;
gameOver1.text = "Score:"+score;
```

You can add strings together with the + operator. When you use Numbers or ints there (or any other type), their toString() function will be called.

Comment: ...if and only if the first term is a string. If the first term is a number and you use the + operator then it'll get confused.

Answer (score 1):

You may want

```
gameOver1.text = "Score: " + int(count1.currentCount/100);
```

If your score needs to show and integer, with no fractional part. Or possibly:

```
gameOver1.text = "Score: " + int((count1.currentCount+50)/100);
```

or

```
gameOver1.text = "Score: " + Math.round(count1.currentCount/100);
```

If you want an integer score but want to round rather than truncate to int (same as floor).

```
gameOver1.text = "Score: " + (count1.currentCount/100).toFixed(2);
```

If you want to display rounded to some fixed number of decimal places (2 places in the example). You may even require:

```
gameOver1.text = "Score: " + Math.ceil(count1.currentCount/100);
```

If you always want to round up.

Answer (score 0):

You can append strings simply by adding them together. So write

```
gameOver1.text = "Score: " + (count1.currentCount / 100).toString();
```